# I need to convert some GeoTIFF images to little endian scaled .R16 (16 bit raw files) for unreal engine import

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff

I have 1188 1/3rd ArcSecond resolution at 1 x 1 degree each which I wish to convert to unreal engines R16 ( Raw format ). I am working at this point in Python.

The problem is I can not tell how to store the data which needs to be stored which ranges from -111.04m to 4414.23m his apparently needs to be multiplied by 100 to put it into unreal units ( centimeters ) and then divided by 512 or if you prefer multiplied by 0.001953125, and the result stored in an unsigned word in little endian format.

Now as far as I have been able to ascertain, unreal .R16 files are Unsigned 16 bit words per height point.

0x0000 is the lowest point, 0x00B0 is the middle point and 0xFFFF is the high point
Bare in mind that the middle value is stored this way but actually reads 0xB000 in hex normally.

So with the range of my values being -111.04 to 4414.23 I will have add 112 to both ends in order to take into account "below sea level values on land" which gives me a range of 0 to 4526.23.

Looking at the top value and multiplying it by 100 I get 452623cm then divide by 512 I get 884.029296875.. Now 884 I can actually store by converting to hi low bytes and storing it but I would lose quite a range of values.

Can anyone tell me how I would store this data in an unreal R16 file without data loss (without referring me to a 3rd party program to do the job)?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Darn, I was hoping someone would know about the R16 format, I already am au fait with Gdal and and am referencing it from Python so I have no problems in that department, the problem I am having is I am trying to take the data I am reading from the Gdal sources, manipulate it through python and write it to an .R16 file - the documentation on the Unreal Engine site is very ambiguous, referring to scaling the data down by multiplying it by a ratio to convert it to a number that fits between -256 and 255.992 which is impossible for byte based data as -256 is of course 9 bits.

Answer (score 0):

The r16 format used by the Unreal Engine (4.0+) is a simply a binary format of two-byte, unsigned integer values. This means it ranges from 0 to 65535 for each height value. There is no metadata so the pixels are the only thing in the file. By example a common 2017x2017 r16 file would be 2017x2017x2 bytes in size. You simply need to strip the metadata from the GeoTiff file (I'm researching how to do this myself which is how I came here) and just use the raw pixel data if you were particularly lazy. But the problem is that that data is *signed* in GeoTIFF. This means the smallest possible value is is 1000000000000000 in binary form (-32767) which indicate "No Height Data". For Unreal you need to convert that value to zero. First convert the integer format to something larger than 16-bit, add 32767, then convert back to a unsigned 16-bit integer. Just stream out each pixel on conversion as-is into your .r16 file with no metadata. Please be aware that the output file must fit within Unreal's limits on file size. Anything larger than that must be split into smaller files and be re-assembled using Unreal's World Partition or Composition systems. In that case each adjacent tile shares a common pixel between them. For a given dimension that means that the number of pixels for the world in that dimension is the number of tiles in that dimension x the resolution of that dimension minus 1. So, for an example tile size of 2017x2017 in a 2x2 grid your world would have dimensions of 4033x4033 pixels. I do my work in C# and I have a library I have built up in that language for manipulating r16 maps for Unreal but I'm not familiar enough with converting that language over to Python to provide a relevant code same. I'm happy to provide my source on request though.